# HTTR equivalent for CURL --form 'file=@"myfile.txt"' - upload file - JIRA Rest API V3

Tags: r, curl, jira-rest-api

Sorry as it is an API question so it hard to provide a reproducible example.

I am trying to add an attachment to a JIRA issue using Jira REST API v3. Below is my code for the POST request.

```
attachment <- POST(
  url = "https://andafin.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/<issue-key>/attachments",
  config = authenticate("user", "apikey", "basic"),
  body = list(x = upload_file("sample_issue_json.json")),
  add_headers("X-Atlassian-Token" = "no-check")
)
```

Which got the following response

```
Response [https://andafin.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/<issue-key>/attachments]
  Date: 2022-08-12 11:26
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Size: 2 B
```

However no attachment was added to the issue on JIRA.
Here is the example for API call CURL if anyone can guide me using `httr` package for this?

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/TEST-123/attachments'
 -u 'email@example.com:<api_token>'
 -H 'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check'
 --form 'file=@"myfile.txt"'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I posted I recognized maybe I should add the body as `file` instead of `x` and it worked.

Here is the example for POST request to add attachment to JIRA issues

```
attachment <- POST(
  url = "https://andafin.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/<issue-key>/attachments",
  config = authenticate("user", "apikey", "basic"),
  body = list(file = upload_file("file_upload.txt")),
  add_headers("X-Atlassian-Token" = "no-check")
)
```